# How to detect someone passing a beacon

Tags: ios, ibeacon, proximity

I'm testing out beacons from Estimote, and I'm wondering what's best practice when it comes to detecting someone passing one or multiple beacons?

Lets say I want to register when people are passing through a door, what is the best way to do that?

So far I think I could make a boolean flag which is initially set to `NO`, and detecting a region of beacons, setting it to `YES` when signal has gone from bad/non-existing to very good and back.

What are your thoughts about this? All feedback is much appreciated!

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "passing" by. Are you talking 2 feet, 30 feet?

Comment: Passing a entrance door, so let's say under 7 feet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very difficult to accomplish, mainly because of delays in beacon detection when an app is not in the foreground.  Typically when a user enters a door, their device is locked and your app is not the foreground.  In such a situation, it can take minutes to detect a beacon in the background.

This makes it very unlikely that your app will see the beacon until well after the user crosses the threshold.

Even if you can get a timely detection, iOS only lets you range for about five seconds in the background after entering a beacon region before suspending your app -- not enough time to measure signal levels as you cross a threshol.  This is especially true considering the range of beacons is about 50 meters, meaning the five second window could start long before you even reach the door.

The only way to do what you suggest is to somehow get the user to have the app in the foreground so you can range constantly.  But this seems unlikely.

Sorry, I know this is not the answer you want to hear.  I have tried to do this several times at client request without success.  The more realistic alternative is to rethink your bigger picture goal and find another way to accomplish it.

Comment: Very good and clear answer. And unfortunately not the answer I was hoping for. However, what about combining the beacons with WiFi detection and/or a geofence?

Comment: The iOS Geofence APIs work very similarly to the iBeacon APIs except they are much more coarse-grained, so they aren't much help.  WiFi detection can work two ways -- detection on the phone (which requires foreground app operation) and detecting by an external sniffer (which cannot be used to determine a specific iOS device because iOS 7+ blocks reading the WiFi mac address.)  Unfortunately, these limitations make these technologies unhelpful in solving this problem.